# error C1189: #error : WINDOWS.H already included. MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>"**

Tags: c++, reference, header

I have a project that use stdafx.h as the precompile header. This means all the cpp file must contain #include "stdafx.h" as the first include.

However, in A.h, I will need to include "afxinet.h", but the compiler complain this

**"error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include "windows.h""**

this is because "afxinet.h" complains when WINDOWS.H i included, but "stdafx.h" does have WINDOWS.H included and is present as the first include in A.cpp.

This implies that I need to somehow have "afxinet.h" included in front of "stdafx.h", but "stdafx.h" is the precompile header and needs to be present as the first include...

how can I resove this dilemma?

Comment: Place afxinet.h in stdafx.h

Comment: Is this a project that uses MFC in any other way?

Answer (score 3):

If your project uses MFC, then you should include its headers in your stdafx.h and not use windows.h (as it will be included by MFC); and if you include windows.h, you cannot use MFC. afxinet.h is a part of MFC, so, I guess, you should either (1) replace your windows.h with afxwin.h and "use MFC" in settings (2) don't use MFC wrappers for WinInet, use functions from Wininet.h

Comment: could you explain more about (1) please. I have to use  "afxinet.h"

Comment: There is #include "windows.h" somewhere in your stdafx.h. Replace it with afxwin.h, include afxinet.h after that and set "this project uses MFC" in project settings; then try to build.